# How to replace "_" with space in R?

Tags: r, special-characters

> levels(problem$value)

"Others"                       "Custom_and_Tax_Issues"        "Copying_Design"               "Dealing_with_buyers"

I want to replace _ with space such as "Custom and Tax Issues"

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
values <- c("Others", "Custom_and_Tax_Issues", "Copying_design", "Dealing_with_buyers")

gsub("_", " ", values)
```